# How to extract the substring from the string?

Tags: android, string, contacts

Actually i have to find today's birthday from contacts. I have the string variable like
    `String value="2014-06-24".`

I want to get the month and date of the of the string variable to compare with today date to find the birthday. Or it has any other methods?

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat and dont do string manipulation with date types

Comment: Please try to split using "-" and month index is (1) and day index is (2).

Comment: Why would somebody split the `String`? `SimpleDateFormat` is much simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormate, if you don not get you can use bellow given method

```
String[] arr = yourStringDate.split("-");
String year = arr[0];
String month = arr[1];
String day = arr[2];
```

Comment: Dont know who dovevoted anf y..?
I think is good solution.Thank you...+1

Comment: I am not the author of this question.

Comment: other than array format it have any format to store

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse dates like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2014-06-24");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // This exception occurs when the String could not be parsed!
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you have `Date` objects you can compare them with `before()` and `after()` like this:

```
if(dateA.after(dateB)) {
    // dateA is after dateB
} else {
    // dateA is before dateB
}
```

You can use a `Calendar` object to get further information from the `Date` object.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: i have a doubt in this. the month from assigned date is 06. but the current month returned as 6. how to compare this

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: ok fine. what value u got from int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

Comment: That returns the current month as integer.

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Just store all your dates as `Date` object and compare them with `before()` and `after()` like I demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way to find date and month from value string:

```
Date date = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    date = formatter.parse(value);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // This exception occurs when the String could not be parsed!
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int birthDay = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int birthMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

then

```
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today =  currentCal.getTime();
```

then you can use date comparison like :

`if(date.before(today) || date.after(today))` and so on for your next operation.